# Is there a noncommutative version of von Neumann's ergodic theorem?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, oa.operator-algebras, ergodic-theory, von-neumann-algebras

The two most celebrated ergodic theorems are Birkhoff's ergodic theorem and von Neumann's ergodic theorem.

E. C. Lance in his remarkable work (*Ergodic Theorems for Convex Sets and Operator Algebras*) formulated that can be considered to be the noncommutative version of Birkhoff's ergodic theorem, for a von Neumann algebra, $T*$-automorphism and a faithful $T$-invariant normal state.

I would like to know whether someone has done the same for von Neumann's ergodic theorem. In other words, is there a noncommutative version of von Neumann's ergodic theorem ?

Comment: Cross-posted and answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3271067/is-there-a-noncommutative-version-of-von-neumanns-ergodic-theorem

Comment: This question would have been on-topic here, in my opinion, but I am voting to close since Tomek has already given an answer over on MSE

Comment: Is Theorem 1 in this post helpful? https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/von-neumann-ergodic-theorem/